# Get header of the C function from BASH

Tags: c, header-file

I want to get the header(s) that I need for a given C function - e.g. when I want to see what to include when I want to use `fork()`, I can type out `man fork` and see that it's `#include <unistd.h>`. However, I'd like to do it "automatically"(without me looking at the screen), so I could redirect output to the file for automatic header insertion. How can I do this?

Comment: You could try something like `man fork | sed -e '/^SYNOPSIS/,/^[A-Z]/!d' -e 's/^ *//' -e '/^#/!d'` but I am afraid there is not really enough consistency in man pages to trust that the information will always be in such a parseable format.

Comment: Maybe Cscope can be scripted to work in such a way? Would be great if it did, that would be actual parsing.

Comment: @TNW I'd actually prefer a more universal way, but if there is none, I could live with other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to write a manpage parser, I think your best bet it to build a text file and fix it up manually.  Start with something like:

```
$ ls /usr/share/man/man2 | sed 's/\.2.*//' \
  | while read F
    do 
      I=$(man $F | grep '#include'| head -1 | sed 's/>.*$/>/')
      printf '%15s:\t%s\n' $F "$I"
    done
```

The first 10 lines I get show an 80% success rate; two pages don't mention an include file:

```
         accept:           #include <sys/types.h>
        accept4:           #include <sys/types.h>
         access:           #include <unistd.h>
           acct:           #include <unistd.h>
        add_key:           #include <keyutils.h>
       adjtimex:           #include <sys/timex.h>
    afs_syscall:
          alarm:           #include <unistd.h>
alloc_hugepages:
     arch_prctl:           #include <asm/prctl.h>
```

Then, to be really lazy, use a little function to search your file, something like

```
$ inc() { awk -F\\t -e "/^ *$1/ "'{print $2}' /tmp/inc; }
$ inc fork
   #include <unistd.h>
```

Beware that some man pages mention more than one header file, depending on features or which function on that page is used.  For an example, see socket(2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any tool that does this job automatically, probably one needs to
 do it manually. First lets find the path from where `gcc` is including files:

```
$ gcc -v

(...)

#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

Now one can `grep` the function definition inside these headers.

In *C* or *C++* each function takes and returns some argument (at least void), also it seems that many linux header files are written in one standard way, so to remove garbage one can surrounded *fork* with spaces and add opening parenthesis at the end:

```
$ headers=(/usr/include /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include-fixed)
$ grep -l ' fork (' ${headers[@]/%//*.h}
/usr/include/unistd.h
```

<sub>(I used here substitution mechanism available in bash and some other shell)</sub>

Obviously one may argue that `grep`ing functional language is not the most brilliant thing ever, but still, for many functions this simple procedure works.